# Using JQuery $.getJSON with a GZipped json file on Apache Server

Tags: javascript, json, apache, gzip

I have a JQuery request to download a JSON file which does not work with my Gzipped Json file. But does work with the non-gzipped file.

**Does not work**

```
var mydata = $.getJSON("data/attributes.json.gz", function() {
  console.log( "downloaded json" );
})
  .fail(function() {
    alert("Failed to get JSON");
  });
```

**Does work**

```
var mydata = $.getJSON("data/attributes.json", function() {
  console.log( "downloaded json" );
})
  .fail(function() {
    alert("Failed to get JSON");
  });
```

I'm running an apache server and have put a `.htaccess` file in the `data` folder:

```
Header set Content-Encoding: gzip
```

Also when I browse to the gzipped file directly in firefox I get the error message

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
```

But headers are being correctly applied, and I have other gzipped files that are working on the same server.

```
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Thu, 07 Jan 2021 15:45:46 GMT
ETag: "bf1f82-5b82b1260edc0-gzip"
Last-Modified: Tue, 05 Jan 2021 18:06:55 GMT
Server: Apache
Vary: Accept-Encoding

Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.5
Connection: keep-alive
DNT: 1
Host: www.wisemover.co.uk
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:84.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/84.0
```